# Kubernetes 1.18.4, iSCSI

Tags: kubernetes, iscsi

I have problems with connecting volume per iSCSI from Kubernetes. When I try with iscisiadm from worker node, it works. This is what I get from kubectl description pod.

```
Normal   Scheduled               <unknown>             default-scheduler        Successfully assigned default/iscsipd to k8s-worker-2
Normal   SuccessfulAttachVolume  4m2s                  attachdetach-controller  AttachVolume.Attach succeeded for volume "iscsipd-rw"
Warning  FailedMount             119s                  kubelet, k8s-worker-2    Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[iscsipd-rw], unattached volumes=[iscsipd-rw default-token-d5glz]: timed out waiting for the condition
Warning  FailedMount             105s (x9 over 3m54s)  kubelet, k8s-worker-2    MountVolume.WaitForAttach failed for volume "iscsipd-rw" : failed to get any path for iscsi disk, last err seen:iscsi: failed to attach disk: Error: iscsiadm: No records found(exit status 21)
```

I'm just using `iscsi.yaml` file from kubernetes.io!

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: iscsipd
spec:
  containers:
  - name: iscsipd-rw
    image: kubernetes/pause
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "/mnt/iscsipd"
      name: iscsipd-rw
  volumes:
  - name: iscsipd-rw
    iscsi:
      targetPortal: 192.168.34.32:3260
      iqn: iqn.2020-07.int.example:sql
      lun: 0
      fsType: ext4
      readOnly: true
```

Open-iscsi is installed on all worker nodes(just two of them).

```
● iscsid.service - iSCSI initiator daemon (iscsid)
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/iscsid.service; enabled; vendor preset: e
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2020-07-03 10:24:26 UTC; 4 days ago
     Docs: man:iscsid(8)
  Process: 20507 ExecStart=/sbin/iscsid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 20497 ExecStartPre=/lib/open-iscsi/startup-checks.sh (code=exited, st
 Main PID: 20514 (iscsid)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 4660)
   CGroup: /system.slice/iscsid.service
           ├─20509 /sbin/iscsid
           └─20514 /sbin/iscsid
```

ISCSI Target is created on the IBM Storwize V7000. Without CHAP.

I tried to connect with iscsiadm from worker node and it works.

```
sudo iscsiadm -m discovery -t sendtargets -p 192.168.34.32
192.168.34.32:3260,1 iqn.1986-03.com.ibm:2145.hq-v7000.hq-v7000-rz1-c1
192.168.34.34:3260,1 iqn.1986-03.com.ibm:2145.hq-v7000.hq-v7000-rz1-c1

sudo iscsiadm -m node --login
Logging in to [iface: default, target: iqn.1986-03.com.ibm:2145.hq-v7000.hq-v7000-rz1-c1, portal: 192.168.34.32,3260] (multiple)
Logging in to [iface: default, target: iqn.1986-03.com.ibm:2145.hq-v7000.hq-v7000-rz1-c1, portal: 192.168.34.34,3260] (multiple)
Login to [iface: default, target: iqn.1986-03.com.ibm:2145.hq-v7000.hq-v7000-rz1-c1, portal: 192.168.34.32,3260] successful.
Login to [iface: default, target: iqn.1986-03.com.ibm:2145.hq-v7000.hq-v7000-rz1-c1, portal: 192.168.34.34,3260] successful.

Disk /dev/sdb: 100 GiB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 32768 bytes / 32768 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x5b3d0a3a

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 209715199 209713152  100G 83 Linux
```

Is anyone facing the same problem?

Comment: Welcome! Are these .yaml files the ones you're supposed to use for this task? If so, consider also filing a bug with kuernetes. Also, if you can clarify what you tried some more, it can help us diagnose your problem.

Comment: Hi and thanks! :) No, they are not. I tried to deploy SQL Container, and got the same problem "No records found(exit status 21) So I just tried with something more simple. And the problem was the same. When I use iscsiadm directly from nodes, it works. Sorry for the format! :( 

"Jul  6 10:29:52 k8s-worker-2 kubelet[1059]: E0706 10:29:52.468632    1059 iscsi_util.go:420] iscsi: failed to get any path for iscsi disk, last err seen:
Jul  6 10:29:52 k8s-worker-2 kubelet[1059]: iscsi: failed to attach disk: Error: iscsiadm:

Answer (score 1):

**Remember to not use a hostname for the target.** Use the IP. For some reason, if the target is a hostname, it barfs with the error about requesting a duplicate session. If the target is an IP, it works fine. I now have multiple iSCSI targets mounted in various pods, and I am absolutely ecstatic.

You may also have authentication issue to your iscsi target.

If you don't use CHAP authentication yet, you still have to disable authentication. For example, if you use  `targetcli`, you can run below commands to disable it.

```
$ sudo targetcli
/> /iscsi/iqn.2003-01.org.xxxx/tpg1 set attribute authentication=0 # will disable auth
/> /iscsi/iqn.2003-01.org.xxxx/tpg1 set attribute generate_node_acls=1 # will force to use tpg1 auth mode by default
```

If this doesn't help you, please share your iscsi target configuration, or guide that you followed.

**What is important check if all of your nodes have the open-iscsi-package installed.**

Take a look: [kubernetes-iSCSI](https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/12433), [volume-failed-iscsi-disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55920173/kubernetes-pod-cannot-mount-iscsi-volume-failed-to-get-any-path-for-iscsi-disk), [iscsi-into-container-fails](https://discuss.kubernetes.io/t/solved-iscsi-into-container-fails/1034).

Comment: Hi, just edited the question. Yes, i used IP and open-iscsi is installed. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. I managed to connect volume directly from nodes without CHAP.  If it helps, I installed kubernetes cluster with kubeadm!

Comment: Did you disable authentication as I mentioned in my answer ? Can you share guide that you followed ?

Comment: Hi, I'm not using targetcli. iSCSI Target is created on IBM Storwize V7000 and without CHAP. I managed to connect from worker node(Ubuntu 18.04, open-iscsi) to target without using CHAP(You can see output in a question). I tried also from Windows, it works. The question is why pod doesn´t get it...I can´t see that the problem is authentication or iSCSI Target, I mean for now ...:), it is more that pod doesn´t see the target nodes(/etc/iscsi/node is empty)?

Comment: Can you paste all this extra information in post in proper format - also these ones from comment directly below your post ?